# Are two calls to the route in Node.js independent of each other? (in context of the event loop and asynchronous db access)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Are the rules of variable scope the same as regular "linear" javascript inside node.js?

I'm making a couple of db calls with the data from some request, the following would be inside of an app.get or app.post function call:

```
var data = req.body.data;
    ----> db SELECT * FROM some table WHERE some value = data;
               -----> db callback declares var resultdata = result.data
                         ----> db SELECT something using BOTH data and resultdata
```

I understand the nature of node.js event loop and that in my case these database calls are async but what if another request comes in on the same route before all callbacks and db requests are finished for the first one. Are the variables preserved/unique to each request? Are two calls to the route above independent of each other?

Comment: Yes, but if a route updates the table while the first query is being completed the second one might reflect different values.

Comment: That depends on the variables. If they're global, the two requests independently access the same variable, if they are closure variables then each request does maintain and preserve its own set of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the two calls are independent of each other because of the event-driven nature of Node.js. All I/O is event driven and asynchronous.

However, Node.js is **single threaded** which means that you cannot do any parallel code execution. For example, it is easy to block the Node.js server with a long running loop ie: parsing a JSON file in the middle of the request-response cycle.

> Since Node.js runs on a single thread, everything that will block the
>   event loop will block everything. That means that if you have a web
>   server with a thousand connected clients and you happen to block the
>   event loop, every client will just...wait.

Source: https://www.airpair.com/node.js/posts/top-10-mistakes-node-developers-make